# Как добавить в новый массив только те элементы массива в которых есть определенные сочетание символов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из элементов:

```
a=[IOfI00,dfImI00,0N0A2D0042N02PDALL,S04ffbLLmD004MLL,afbvdasMLL]
```

как вытащить только те элементы, где есть выражение "MLL" и добавить их в новый массив?

Answer (score 4):

```js
const arr = ['IOfI00', 'dfImI00', '0N0A2D0042N02PDALL', 'S04ffbLLmD004MLL', 'afbvdasMLL'];
const result = arr.filter(v => v.includes('MLL'));
console.log(result);
```